# Neglected effects of special relativity for the case of a fall into a black hole?

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

It has been said that falling into a black hole and crossing the event horizon would appear as "nothing out the ordinary" for the in-faller (especially for a super-massive BH, but lack of strong tidal forces is not my concern here).

When falling towards the event horizon (actually towards a collapsing star because the event horizon has not yet formed in the frame of any outsider, but let this be a non-issue here as well) one would get accelerated to the vacuum speed of light once reaching the event horizon.

That must mean that in the in-fallers frame of reference, the entire universe would get infinitely length-contracted in the direction of travel (which I did not see mentioned anywhere) i.e. "2D'd", but also, even the tiniest particle would have infinite kinetic energy, i.e. it would have **infinite mass-energy** (while being confined in a volume of precisely zero). Isn't that a problem?

At least, to my understanding that would be quite the opposite of "nothing out the ordinary".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply special relativity in curved spacetime, except locally, within the immediate neighbourhood of an observer.

From the point of view of an exterior observer, one is not accelerated to the vacuum speed of light, but actually one stops before crossing the event horizon. It happens that light stops too, but this is rather different from being accelerated to the same speed.

In the infaller's frame of reference, light continues to move at the speed of light. This is indeed "nothing out of the ordinary". But the infaller's frame of reference applies only locally to himself. It makes no statement about the entire universe. Even to talk about the entire universe, he would have to choose coordinates. But coordinates are a human choice, and a different choice would give a different description. This does not say anything about the universe until we know how the choice of coordinates has been made.

Comment: If a spaceship moves with 0.5 * c relative to, let's say, Earth, then, in the frame of reference of the spaceship, the rest of the entire universe is moving past it with 0.5 * c. - If a spaceship falls towards a black hole, in the frame of reference of the ship, the rest of the universe moves past it faster and faster, reaching relativistic velocities. Why would length contraction and time dilation not be imployed any more?

Comment: No. Only local comparisons are possible. You cannot make such comparisons in any meaningful way.  It is like comparing the directions NW at different parts of the Earth's surface.

Comment: So how would the rest of the universe behave, as observed/measured in the frame of a spaceship falling radially into a black hole? There must be a way/transformation to calculate that.

Comment: It depends on the coordinate system used to describe it. Just as a map of the Earth looks very different depending on how you choose to draw the map.

Answer (score 1):

> It has been said that falling into a black hole and crossing the event horizon would appear as "nothing out the ordinary" for the in-faller (especially for a super-massive BH [...]).

That's correct. In the case of a large black hole, even fairly large regions in the vicinity of the event horizon are roughly flat (i.e. roughly just look like Minkowski space).

> When falling towards the event horizon (actually towards a collapsing star because the event horizon has not yet formed in the frame of any outsider [...])

I think you're making the mistake here of thinking that something that isn't in your past (i.e. that you haven't seen happen yet) must be in your future (i.e. hasn't happened yet). In Newtonian physics there's a division into past and future with the present as the boundary, but in relativity there's a division into past, future, and "elsewhere" (spacelike separated), with the light cone as the boundary. As long as you're outside the event horizon, the surface portion of the star crossing the horizon can't be in your past, by the definition of event horizon. If you're early to the party, then it may be in your future, in which case you could actually hit the star before it crosses the event horizon if you hurry. More likely, though, it's spacelike separated from you, meaning the star objectively becomes a black hole before you cross the horizon.

> one would get accelerated to the vacuum speed of light once reaching the event horizon.

You aren't accelerated to the speed of light.

If you want to stay outside the event horizon, then you have to accelerate, and the necessary rate of acceleration goes to infinity as the distance to the horizon goes to zero. But this is equally true in special relativity with a lightlike surface such as $x=t$. If you want to stay in the region $x>t$, you have to accelerate in the $+x$ direction. If you don't care about staying in that region, you can just fall inertially through the surface, and you won't accelerate at all. Any sufficiently small patch near the event horizon of a black hole is roughly isomorphic to a patch of Minkowski space, the event horizon is a lightlike surface similar to the $x=t$ surface, and the physics of crossing it is roughly the same.

Comment: At the event horizon, escape velocity is the vacuum velocity of light. Why would you not get accelerated to the speed of light on a geodesic from infinitely far away to the event horizon of a black hole?

Comment: @Felix-Tritschler The *Newtonian* escape velocity is $c$. Dimensional analysis suggests that the formula for that and the formula for the Schwarzschild radius will be proportional, and the proportionality constant happens to be 1 and not, say, 2 as it is in the case of the deflection of starlight. Nothing with mass can go at the speed $c$ and black holes are no exception to that. The escape-velocity argument never made sense anyway since escape velocity is for ballistic motion and escape to infinity, whereas you can't escape any distance out of a black hole even with a rocket engine.

Comment: Well, that's what I meant with "Isn't that a problem?". Meanwhile, I actually found this here: https://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/bh/singularity.html#r=1 - "Relative to an observer stationary in the Schwarzschild metric, our velocity has now reached the speed of light." - Later, it is said that this doesn't contradict special relativity because space, itself, is moving (which I found strange).

Comment: In response to the second paragraph of your answer: Every event in space-time that is in, e.g. my, frame of reference, i.e. equitemporal for me and happening right now for me, is space-like-separated from me (in this case). In a Minkowski diagram depicting my frame as stationary, it is every point on the x-axis (which is obviously outside "my" light cone. And these events (on the x-axis) do happen, right now for me. But if something hasn't happened, yet, in my frame of reference, it hasn't happened, yet, in my frame of reference. I made no mistake in this regard.

Comment: @FelixTritschler I don't know what they meant by that quote. Schwarzschild coordinate speed goes to 0 near the horizon. Eddington-Finkelstein and Kruskal-Szekeres coordinate speeds are less than c at the horizon. I think the text is simply wrong. The simulations are correct as far as I know. Re your last comment, there's no such thing as "my frame of reference" or "equitemporal for me"; all coordinate systems are equivalent and there's no "correct" one for any worldline. Past/future/elsewhere are coordinate independent and physically meaningful, unlike coordinate simultaneity.

Comment: @FelixTritschler After thinking about it, I bet they mean that if you calculate the velocity in local inertial coordinates "aligned with" the Schwarzschild coordinates, i.e. divide the Schwarzschild velocity by $1-2m/r$, then that goes to $c$. That's because the coordinates are singular at the horizon. Rindler coordinates have the same singularity, and there are Rindler horizons everywhere, so the same argument shows that you're always accelerating to $c$ in all directions at every instant whether there's a black hole around or not.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. What do you mean with "there's no such thing as "my frame of reference" ..." and "all coordinate systems are equivalent"? Of course, different observers have different realities, so to say. This is the very essence of relativity.

Comment: ... E.g. a space traveler moving with 0.6 c relative to Earth, while passing Earth, will say that a certain spacetime event 2.4 lyrs ahead of him/her happens right now (on his/her clock and the distance measured with his/her standards),but on Earth we would say that this spacetime event happens in 1.8 years 3 lyrs away from us. Another example that fits here ideally: Somebody accellerating constantly without ever stopping will have have a region behind them, at a certain distance, where time stops for them and certain spacetime events will never happen (for them).